# Error on editing an existing issue in Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to set the assignee field to an existing issue in Jira using the Rest api call.
I am getting the error: "Field 'assignee' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
I am making a PUT call to "https//:{jira-server}/rest/api/2/issue/OPCP-32" where OPCP-32 is the issue id.
Is it an error related to permissions or am I doing anything wrong?
My json looks like this: http://pastebin.com/56TMMTCN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission related issue. Got the necessary permissions and it is working as expected.